# pika consuming from thread ignores KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to run the following test using pika 0.10.0 from github:

```py
import logging
import sys
import pika
import threading

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/%2F?socket_timeout=0.25'


class BaseConsumer(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        self._connection = None
        self._channel = None
        self.connect()
        self.open_channel()
        self.consume()

    def connect(self):
        parameters = pika.URLParameters(URL)
        self._connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

    def open_channel(self):
        self._channel = self._connection.channel()
        self._channel.exchange_declare(exchange='exc1', exchange_type='topic', passive=False,
                                       durable=False, auto_delete=False, internal=False, arguments=None)
        self._channel.queue_declare(queue='test', passive=False, durable=False,
                                    exclusive=False, auto_delete=False, arguments=None)
        self._channel.queue_bind(
            'test', 'exc1', routing_key='rk', arguments=None)

    def consume(self):
        self._channel.basic_consume(self.on_message, 'test')
        try:
            self._channel.start_consuming()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logging.info("Stop consuming now!")
            self._channel.stop_consuming()
        self._connection.close()

    def on_message(self, channel, method_frame, header_frame, body):
        print method_frame.delivery_tag
        print body
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)

c1 = BaseConsumer()
c1.setDaemon(False)
c1.start()
```

The script is connecting to my MQ and is apparently able to consume messages from the MQ. The problem is that I have no way of stoping the thread. Pressing CTRL-C on my keyboard only causes "^C" to appear in the console without interrupting the consume.

Question is, how do I make pika stop consuming when it is running inside of a thread ? I would like to note that I am following the guidelines of creating the connection in the consumer thread.

If after starting the thread with c1.start() I also do an infinite while loop and log something from there then pressing CTRL-C will end the while loop but the consumer thread will still ignore any additional CTRL-C.

Side question: is it possible to stop consuming inside the thread with some outside signalling like a threading.Condition or something ? I don't see how i can interfere with start_consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: ... from there then pressing CTRL-C will end the while loop

Add a `def stop()` to your `BaseConsumer`,
catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` and call `stop()`.

```
try: 
    BaseConsumer.run() 
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    BaseConsumer.stop()
```

Read [pika: asynchronous_consumer_example](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html)